# Flask run error, not working - term not recognised

Tags: python, flask

Testing out an apps.py in my environment project directory, this is my script for a login/register form:

```js
#app.py
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash
from django.apps import AppConfig
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
import psycopg2 #pip install psycopg2 
import psycopg2.extras
import re 
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

#
class IndexConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'index'
#
 
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'cairocoders-ednalan'
 
DB_HOST = "localhost"
DB_NAME = "users"
DB_USER = "postgres"
DB_PASS = "admin"
 
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST)
 
@app.route('/')
def home():
    # Check if user is loggedin
    if 'loggedin' in session:
    
        # User is loggedin show them the home page
        return render_template('home.html', username=session['username'])
    # User is not loggedin redirect to login page
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
 
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
   
    # Check if "username" and "password" POST requests exist (user submitted form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        print(password)
 
        # Check if account exists using MySQL
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s', (username,))
        # Fetch one record and return result
        account = cursor.fetchone()
 
        if account:
            password_rs = account['password']
            print(password_rs)
            # If account exists in users table in out database
            if check_password_hash(password_rs, password):
                # Create session data, we can access this data in other routes
                session['loggedin'] = True
                session['id'] = account['id']
                session['username'] = account['username']
                # Redirect to home page
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
            else:
                # Account doesnt exist or username/password incorrect
                flash('Incorrect username/password')
        else:
            # Account doesnt exist or username/password incorrect
            flash('Incorrect username/password')
 
    return render_template('login.html')
  
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
 
    # Check if "username", "password" and "email" POST requests exist (user submitted form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form:
        # Create variables for easy access
        fullname = request.form['fullname']
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
    
        _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)
 
        #Check if account exists using MySQL
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s', (username,))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        print(account)
        # If account exists show error and validation checks
        if account:
            flash('Account already exists!')
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
            flash('Invalid email address!')
        elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', username):
            flash('Username must contain only characters and numbers!')
        elif not username or not password or not email:
            flash('Please fill out the form!')
        else:
            # Account doesnt exists and the form data is valid, now insert new account into users table
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (fullname, username, password, email) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (fullname, username, _hashed_password, email))
            conn.commit()
            flash('You have successfully registered!')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # Form is empty... (no POST data)
        flash('Please fill out the form!')
    # Show registration form with message (if any)
    return render_template('register.html')
   
   
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # Remove session data, this will log the user out
   session.pop('loggedin', None)
   session.pop('id', None)
   session.pop('username', None)
   # Redirect to login page
   return redirect(url_for('login'))
  
@app.route('/profile')
def profile(): 
    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
   
    # Check if user is loggedin
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = %s', [session['id']])
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        # Show the profile page with account info
        return render_template('profile.html', account=account)
    # User is not loggedin redirect to login page
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the error I receive when I run 'flask run' in the terminal, not sure what it means at all.

What I'm trying to achieve is connecting psql database to my website and using flask as the web framework

```
PS C:\Users\sefni\Documents\test_django_app\Environments\testProject> flask run
flask : The term 'flask' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ flask run
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flask:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Have you tried `python app.py`?

Answer (score 2):

Either you have not installed `flask`. You should do:

```
pip install flask
```

---

Or you are not running the application correctly. You run like this (from the directory where your code is):

```
python -m flask run
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run the app using app.run() in your case you need to execute python app.py

but If you want it to run using flask run then you need to set the env
executing the two commands.

```
set FLASK_APP=application.py
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

now you can run the app using the below line

```
flask run
```

if you are using bash then use `export` in place of `set`. [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/) for reference

Comment: seems to have worked with set FLASK_APP=apps.py, would that be correct?

Comment: application.py will be replaced by the name of file you want to run. And FLASK_DEBUG=1 is for enabling debug mode. Default debug mode is 0 which means off.